# How to manage multiply react native applications using different configuration per application, while sharing code?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, react-native

I'm new to react native. I'm planning to create several react native applications that are going to reuse some code.
The code they are going to share is the session management, api, storage manager, formatters, etc...
**these are not React Native Components!**

So I want to organize these projects in the following structure:

- app_1 *(different package.json)*
- app_2 *(different package.json)*
- app_n *(different package.json)*
- package_that_every_app_imports *(different package.json)*

My problem is that some modules in project_that_every_app_includes will have to be configured per application.

In order to do so I'm thinking that I could set a global variable that all modules even from different packages would have access to.

Is there any better approach to configure the modules of package_that_every_app_imports rather than this?
(except of course by passing configuration into the constructor of an instances)

**UPDATE 1:**
After playing around it seems that when I set a global variable in the app_1 the global variable is not available in the package_that_every_app_imports so the initial guess is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a bit more research I stumble upon this package called
[react-native-config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-config)

This package allows me to create/manage different configurations environments (development, production, etc...) using .env files.

.env example:

```
BASE_URL=http://staging.example.org/
ENVIRONMENT=staging
```

The variables can be access like:

```
import Config from "react-native-config";
const base_url = Config.BASE_URL;
```

Config also can be accessed in modules of package_that_every_app_imports without any problems.